# gosec linter: G101: Potential hardcoded credentials

Tags: go, static-analysis, gosec

I get this message from the `gosec` linter:

```
foo/cloud.go:34:2: G101: Potential hardcoded credentials (gosec)
        fooAPIKeyENVVar = "Foo_API_KEY"
```

How to disable this warning?

Answer (score 5):

This make the warning to get skipped:

```
fooAPIKeyENVVar = "Foo_API_KEY" // #nosec G101
```